# python: multiple SQLs to run in parallel

Tags: python-multiprocessing, python-3.7

My python program is supposed to execute approx 200 SQLs. 200 (**inptLstCnt**) is based on the number of tables received as the input to the function.

Instead running 200 SQLs one by one, i want use the same database connection instance, run 10 or certain pool of SQLs at a time and iterate until the **inptLstCnt** is met. I am quite confused what to choose between Multiprocessing pools and Threads.

Are there any code references for similar approach but not necessarily SQL execution or database connection.